# Foreign key sqlite 3 remove 1-n register

Tags: php, sqlite, yii

I have 2 tables, in sqlite 3

Control and User.

The control have the
Name, user_id.

I want to delete the control when i delete the user.
So, if i delete all users with id = 10 i want to delete all controls with user_id = 10.
Is there a way to do that in the database.
I'm already doing the CONSTRAINT "fk_user_id" FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "tbl_user" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE, and no luck.
The records still there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

```
'db'=>array(
    'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
    'initSQLs'=>array(
    'PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON',
     ),
),
```

Need to add pragma to enable the foreign keys on init